# Как выбрать input.value у компонента React?

Tags: reactjs

Мне нужно добавлять введенные данные из input.value в массив.

```
addWord() {
let word = // получить слово из input //;
this.state.words.push(word); }
```

Сам массив находится в стейтах:

```
 state = {
words: ["cat", "bat", "doggo", "why", "hello", "abracadbra"] }
```

Что я пишу в render():

```
<input
        placeholder="add new word"
        type="text"
        className="new-word"
        onChange={this.addWord()}
      />
```

Буду очень благодарен за вашу помощь.

Comment: у вас на каждое изменение поля ввода будет вызываться метод который не работает. Нужно какую нибудь кнопку рядом положить для отправки

Comment: `onChange={(ev) => this.addWord(ev.target.value)}`